# Why won't Java delete my file even though the file is closed?

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, delete-file

I know that this question has been asked and answered many times on this site. The basic solutions are:
(1) Make sure the file is closed.
(2) Ensure the program has the absolute path.

As far as (1) goes, I took the project out of the OneDrive folder (which would usually try an sync it to the cloud), and made sure to close the Scanner reading the file. Still nothing.
For (2), the file is in the same directory as the project. Additionally, I used the `getAbsoluteFile()` method and assigned it to my `file` variable. (I also tried without it, still, didn't go).

I'm operating on Windows.

```
File file = new File(newFile);
        Scanner printer = new Scanner(file);
        while (printer.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = printer.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        printer.close();
        try {
            boolean deleted = file.delete();
            if (deleted)
                System.out.println("The file has been successfully deleted.");
            else
                System.out.println("The file has not been deleted.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

output is The file has not been deleted

Comment: What does it output when you run it?

Comment: Side note: consider to use the NIO.2 File API instead of the legacy java.io.File API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html

Comment: Side note: consider to use try-with-resource when working with AutoCloseable classes such as Scanner.

Comment: @thatotherguy, the output is `The file has not been deleted.`

Comment: 1) use java.nio.file.Files for I/O 2) if you really wanna go manual, user try-resource, as stated by Puce 3) if it is imperative that the file gets deleted, close the stream, then use a while loop that checks it 4) check out java.io.File.deleteOnExit(); that deletes files when the JVM shuts down 5) check java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists. => they all might pose options for your problem

Answer (score 0):

Consider inserting the while loop inside the try structure

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, FileNotFoundException {
        
        File file = new File("newFile.txt");
        Scanner printer=null;
        
        try {
            printer = new Scanner(file);
            while (printer.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = printer.nextLine();
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            printer.close();
            boolean deleted = file.delete();
            if (deleted)
                System.out.println("The file has been successfully deleted.");
            else
                System.out.println("The file has not been deleted.");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        
        finally {
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I used a .txt file to test this code and it worked pretty fine, if it does not work on your specific file type please tell me. Have a nice day!

Comment: I am using a .txt file as well. I tried your code, but it still does not work. Not sure what I'm overlooking here.

Answer (score 0):

The Files / NIO calls usually give much better error messages than File / IO - including reasons why cannot delete a file, so try replacing `file.delete()` with:

```
Files.delete(file.toPath());
```

If you see that the file only deletes when VM exits or fails to delete then a possible  cause is that your code is not clearing resources correctly. Because you don't use `try()` with resources you may have an error in another part of your file handling - or a stream of files - that has failed to do proper cleanup and is blocking this delete.